# Graphics Corruption even during Boot, then after 2 failed reboots it says BOOTMGR is missing

Tags: boot, crash, hardware-failure, filesystem-corruption, amd-graphics-card

I'm encountering a very frustrating and confusing problem with my desktop and I am really hoping someone has experienced either a similar problem or knows what I can do to fix this.

To start off, here are my system specs:

- CPU: AMD FX8120
- RAM: Ripjaw 2x 8GB DDR3 1333Mhz
- HDD: 1 Samsung 1TB, 1 WD 160GB and 1 Seagates 2TB
- GPU: Asus 7950 Direct CU II (the one with the massive heatsink)
- Mobo: AMD Sabertooth 990FX
- PSU: Coolermaster Silent Pro 700W (Modular)
- OS: Windows 7 Latest Version
- Graphics Drivers: Latest Stable Version on AMD

I've been using it for roughly 2-3 years without any major issues (though Windows 7 has a few minor driver issues with the network adapter from time to time, but that's about it).

Now one night, I was playing a game on my desktop and suddenly there was major graphic corruption (lots of weird horizontal bars that garbled the screen) until an eventual system crash.

When it started up, even from the bios there was more graphical corruption (2 vertical bars) and the usual startup repair (was not able to do anything). I restarted and checked the BIOS (it's using UEFI), and all the vitals and thermals seemed within safe ranges (51C for CPU and 33C for the mobo). I switched to AMD optimized defaults in case it might do something and restarted.

It loaded into the login screen with more graphic corruption (attaching a photo). When I tried to login, it suddenly turned white with graphic corruption (with more vertical and horizontal bars). After the next reboot, it now says that the BOOTMGR is missing, but it is in this kind of garbled text where the 'l's are replaced with something like ||.

I don't really know what's wrong or the extent of the damage, but I'm really hoping someone here has an idea. It is really killing me inside because I built the whole thing myself and now it's dying on me.

Massive thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

[Here is the photo I took of the login screen with graphic corruption, it actually got worse later on though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlHVa.jpg)

Comment: you can try to clear cmos or another graphic card to see if it comes from efi or graphic card

Comment: Try a different video card, if it has onboard video on the motherboard remove the Asus card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BOOTMGR is missing` message has nothing to do with your current problem. The restarts made your operating system damaged and it is no longer able to boot. It is easy to fix this, just follow these steps:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2622803

According to your picture this can be caused by multiple problems, firs of all I would verify the cable between the monitor and the PC if it is plugged in correctly, next if your motherboard has an integrated GPU, you should give it a try by connecting your monitor to it, or connecting your monitor to another device.
This way you can find out if it is a problem with your monitor or your GPU.

Comment: However, if the failed restarts were caused by the graphic corruption then doesn't that make it impossible for the problem to be with my monitor? also, is it just my operating system? meaning the rest of my files are probably secure?

Comment: Replacing my GPU worked, now using an R9 390. One of my HDDs failed to powerup after (funny enough, not the one with Windows on it but the one I use to store movies, series and games) so I just replaced that. However now I'm experiencing another peculiar error and I made a different post on that (http://superuser.com/questions/1061667/frequent-bsods-on-windows-7-professional-after-replacing-graphics-card-worked-f/1061922?noredirect=1#comment1492958_1061922). I am now extremely tempted to just build a new one from scratch already... Thank you so much though!