# Windows 10 bluescreens on startup

Tags: windows-10, bsod, windows-update

Windows 7 forced me to update to Windows 10 about 2 weeks ago. It ran okay for awhile, but most morning when I wake up it is out of sleep mode for no specific reason.

I found closing the lid seemed to stop it from starting randomly. This morning I found out my computer had turned itself on from sleep mode, and had also crashed at some stage. When starting up it BSODs while Windows is loading (SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION with no further information).

I have tried loading from a restore point, but windows 10 did not make one.

I did manage to launch Safe Mode using the legacy system. I checked the logs and the reason for tonight's startup seems to be the windows 10 updater.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

### Files

[image: Device manage]

Windows build 10586 (If I remembered correctly.)

This is a [dmp file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1rH5lP63CDCMlhoZDhtWExsRHc) it made earlier today.

### Fix

As said in the answer of magicandre1981, the rift driver seems to be the problem. So I deleted it from the registry and then I deleted the driver itself.
[image: Delete rift from registry]
[image: Delete rift driver]

It looks like everything is fixed now! May still revert to Windows 7 though :)

Comment: Windows 10 has the ability to roll back to the previous version, restore points isn't how you do that, but the process is well documented.  If its been only 2 weeks then this is indeed still possible.

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\windows\minidump so that we can debug the crash and help you to fix it

Comment: I have recently answered to a similar question of how to troubleshoot BSOD. You can try following the steps it might solve your problem.
http://superuser.com/questions/1061667/frequent-bsods-on-windows-7-professional-after-replacing-graphics-card-worked-f/1063274#1063274

Comment: I am aware I can still go back to Windows 7, which was not the point. But on second thought Windows 10 has been nothing but trouble to me and windows 7 works (or worked) great. Another question I do though have is, do you think it's safe to revert to windows 7 while the only way to startup my computer is in safe mode?

Comment: Also @Divin3 Thanks, that could probably work, but running sigverif.exe gives me an entirely different bluescreen. (DRIVER_VERIFIER_IOMANAGER_VIOLATION (USBPcap.sys)) Or is that the point and do I now know what the problem is?

Comment: I hope that first comment didn't sound too arrogant, I'm under huge stress right now and I desperately need my computer within like 2 hours. Can anyone confirm if it is safe (or at least safe enough) to downgrade back to windows 7 with my computer in a state where it won't start up normally?

Comment: you probably have a driver problem, downgrading may solve the problem, but not 100%. Could you post a screenshot of your device manager?

Comment: @Divin3 I added a screenshot, is that the device manager you were talking about?

Comment: First try some antivirus and antimalware software. Than we will try to troubleshoot the rest of the possibilities. For now, I am a bit busy at work. I will try to answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I see, thank you anyway. Clicking Update and Security in the windows 10 settings panel doesn't seem to work so I don't know how to downgrade back to windows 7. (already ran some antivirus).

Comment: I'm (literally) getting sick of the stress. Time to load an image backup. Again thanks for trying to help me! And @Divin3 good luck at work!

Comment: A clean install of Windows would be the best for you. Is that a possible option for you?

Comment: I may have to, the image backup just finished (It looks like it anyway) and I still get the same bluescreen :(

Almost making me think I have a hardware issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fro mthe dmp file I can see that the crash is caused by a driver called `RiftEnabler.sys`

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: 0000000000000000, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffffd001819b3560, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for RiftEnabler.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for RiftEnabler.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.212.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160328-1908

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: c0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd001819b3560

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
00000000`00000000 ??              ???

CONTEXT:  ffffd001819b3560 -- (.cxr 0xffffd001819b3560)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=ffffc000e9358430
rdx=0000000000000001 rsi=ffffe00007e01000 rdi=ffffc000e9358430
rip=0000000000000000 rsp=ffffd001819b3f88 rbp=ffffe00007e01000
 r8=ffffd001819b4010  r9=ffffe000077671a0 r10=0000000067617246
r11=ffffe00008300000 r12=ffffe000075a1000 r13=0000000000000001
r14=ffffd001819b4010 r15=0000000000000001
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010286
00000000`00000000 ??              ???
Resetting default scope

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: 9be

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff801f06d4537 to 0000000000000000

IP_IN_FREE_BLOCK: 0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd001`819b3f88 fffff801`f06d4537 : fffff800`4b517df0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff800`4b517c88 : 0x0
ffffd001`819b3f90 fffff800`4b517df0 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff800`4b517c88 ffffe000`077671a0 : RiftEnabler+0x4537
ffffd001`819b3f98 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 fffff800`4b517c88 ffffe000`077671a0 00000000`00000000 : nt!NonPagedPoolDescriptor+0x12b0


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
RiftEnabler+4537
fffff801`f06d4537 85c0            test    eax,eax

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  2179c085

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  RiftEnabler+4537

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: RiftEnabler

IMAGE_NAME:  RiftEnabler.sys
```

If you use Oculus Rift, update the driver, otherwise remove it completely.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found a way to get rid of that rift stuff (I'll post some screenshots) and it works again! I still don't understand how this was still a problem after I put my image backup back though, does that not change the registry or something?

Comment: maybe the driver was already installed when you captured the image

Comment: But how is it a problem now and not then though, while the system is exactly the same.

Comment: some bugs in software (apps/drivers) are triggered randomly. I have no idea why it happens now